# Replace string if it contains certain substring in PySpark

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Need to update a PySpark dataframe if the column contains the certain substring

for example:

df looks like

```
id      address
1       spring-field_garden
2       spring-field_lane
3       new_berry place
```

If the address column contains `spring-field_` just replace it with `spring-field`.

Expected result:

```
id      address
1       spring-field
2       spring-field
3       new_berry place
```

Tried:

```
df = df.withColumn('address',F.regexp_replace(F.col('address'), 'spring-field_*', 'spring-field'))
```

Seems not working.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `like` with `when` expression:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn(
    'address',
    F.when(
        F.col('address').like('%spring-field_%'),
        F.lit('spring-field')
    ).otherwise(F.col('address'))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
df.withColumn(
    'address',
    F.regexp_replace('address', r'.*spring-field.*', 'spring-field')
)
```

Alternatively you can use the method `contains`:

```
df.withColumn(
    'address',
    F.when(
        F.col('address').contains("spring-field"), "spring-field"
    ).otherwise(F.col('address'))
)
```